# Mock is failing in If condition

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

In my controller, i am doing a validation check in `if` block using a validator class.

Since validation code is not complete yet i just want to test that if
validation was successful the response should be 201(Success).

For this i am mocking the behaviour of validator object to return `true`
i.e its valid.

The problem is even if i have mocked the validator object behaviour to not enter `if` block so it doesn't throw validation Exception, its actually entering and throwing exception. That means mocking hasn't worked. I know its bad to assume the method implementation for testing, but i want to know why its not working.

*myController.class*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/api")
public class myController {


    @Autowired
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Autowired
    RequestValidator validator;

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody
    BaseResponse<Response> create(@RequestBody Request<Data> request){


        if(!validator.isValidRequestObject(request))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("invalid request");
        }

        Response data = requestService.submitData(request);
        BaseResponse<Response> response = new BaseResponse<Response>();
        response.setData(data); 
        response.setMessage("Created Successfully");
        return response;


    }
```

*ControllerTest.class*

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    Request<Data> request;

    @MockBean
    RequestService service;

    @MockBean
    RequestValidator validator;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void createTest() throws Exception {

        when(validator.isValidRequestObject(request)).thenReturn(true);
        when(service.submitData(request)).thenReturn(null);

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/api")
                             .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                             .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    }
```

If i remove the `throw new exception` line, test passes.
i assume that since i have mocked `validator` behaviour in `myController`
that should not enter if block and hence not throw Exception.
But its entering the `if` block and throwing exception defying the mocked behaviour.

Comment: The request you're serializing and the request passed to the validator after deserialization are most probably not equal.

Comment: but i have mocked the validation behaviour to always return true i.e valid. So no matter what object i pass it should return true.

Comment: i have got the answer, its just a line change

when(validator.isValidMandateRequestObject(any(MandateRequest.class))).thenReturn(true);